# Odoo accounting wants to change tax in paid invoices

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to reset tax in invoice just because I have proceed sales order and invoice with wrong tax. So how could I do this.

[image]

That I would like to achieve using code or manual.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the module `account_cancel` which will allow a cancellation of journal entries for special configured journals.

After installation you can configure journals, but you have to be in debug mode to see this option in journals.

In your example it should be the "Sales Journal". After configuring the journal, you can cancel the invoice and set it back to draft. Now just change the tax and validate the invoice again. You will get the same invoice number.

Attention: in some countries such accounting data manipulation is forbidden.

Comment: What about it's payment entry ? Payment entries are also done for invoice.

Comment: If you already have a payment on an invoice, you have cancel the reconciliation before being able to cancel the invoice itself. After editing the invoice and validating, there should be no problem to add the payment again (in Odoo 10 it's very easy).

Comment: Okay got it, what if there are multiple entries and can you please help me to make small script or any hint on this.

Comment: In older versions the reconciliation was an object itself, so there is a function or a wizard to "undo" it. The other invoice part is used with functions, too, for example `action_cancel` and `validate`. For adding existing payments again, i have no idea, sorry.